# ¿Cómo crear un header usando "sticky" y "fixed"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

me encontraba con la siguiente problemática, me encuentro un header y quería que tenga el siguiente comportamiento (pongo colores fuertes para que se note).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención era *scrollear* para abajo y que ese *nav* negro funcione como _sticky?, desplazándose hasta que llegue a la siguiente sección de la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de ahi (cuando se termina lo rojo) quería que ese *navbar* se quede *fixed* a la parte de arriba y no lo estoy consiguiendo de ninguna manera.

Por lo que estuve probando, hay una forma en la que, *scrolleando* a partir de determinada posición Y de la pagina, yo pueda cambiar la clase de ese *nav* y poner lo que quiera; pero no me termina de convencer.
¿Conocen alguna forma de hacer esto mismo? ¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: El formato del sitio no permite respuestas basadas en opiniones, ya que incitan al debate, y pedir recomendaciones tiende a generar respuestas basadas en opiniones. Sugiero que cambies la redacción de tu pregunta. También incluir el código que has intentado puede aumentar las probabilidades de encontrar ayuda, pues generalmente los miembros de la comunidad prefieren explicar cómo resolver un problema concreto y no realizar un requerimiento o tarea desde cero. Para más información, lee [ask] y [mcve].

Comment: No entiendo lo que necesitas, el comportamiento  de `sticky` es justamente quedar como `fixed` al hacer scroll, por lo que supongo que necesitas otra cosa.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código? **Creo** que no se puede hacer solo con CSS. Necesitarás cambiar el atributo de `position: relative` a `position: fixed` por javascript cuando se cumplan las condiciones deseadas.